# Node / Socket.io cookies not sent during Handshaking

Tags: http, node.js, cookies, dns, socket.io

I'm facing a strange problem : I have a cookie set on my domain for the path / that I want to grab during handshake server-side to check if cookies is valid etc.... The thing is that my cookies are not sent during the XHR call to authorize: there are some screenshots :

http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg252/scaled.php?server=252&filename=capturedcran20120201130.png&res=medium

But the strange thing is that when I request the socket.io.js Cookies are sent... Like actually they should for any HTTP call on my server...

http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/9008/capturedcran20120201130.png

Thanks by advance!

Comment: I do have the same issue. In my case I'm serving the HTML page and associated JS files through port 80, but then ask socket.io client to connect through another port. Do you have the same kind of double port thing in your app ?